# How can I list all partition keys in Azure Table Storage?

Tags: azure-table-storage

I'm trying to look at what's inside an Azure Table Storage from the CLI.

If I try to list all entites, it says it requires the partition key:

```
az storage entity show --table-name Device
the following arguments are required: --partition-key, --row-key
```

Is there any way to list all partition keys with the az command?

Also, is it not possible to just list all entities without a partition key?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to list all partition keys with the az command?

No, it is not possible to do so. You would need to list all entities.

> Also, is it not possible to just list all entities without a partition
> key?

Sure, the CLI command you would want to use is [`az storage entity query`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/entity?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-entity-query). Because you want to fetch all entities, do not include `--filter` parameter. So your command would be something like:

```
az storage entity query --table-name Device
```